# CodeIgniter and utf8 functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, multilingual

My site needs to support multiple languages so it needs to handle utf8 data throughout the site. I understand how to configure codeigniter for utf8 data with regards to interacting with the database. My question is how does codeigniter handle things like rules for form fields when using utf8 encoding? For instance using strlen, for utf8 the strlen would be different and so you would need to use the mbstring function for that instead, mb_strlen. Does codeigniter have a setup that automatically handles that or is there something I need to configure inside codeigniter to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does use mb_strlen by default if it is accessible:

```
//below default min_length function of CI_Form_Validation lib as an example

/**
 * Minimum Length
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   value
 * @return  bool
 */
function min_length($str, $val)
{
    if (preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $val))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (function_exists('mb_strlen'))
    {
        return (mb_strlen($str) < $val) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    return (strlen($str) < $val) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

For preg_match functions use unicode modifier:

```
// native CI alpha function:
function alpha($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

// ready for unicode using u modifier in regex pattern
function alpha($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z])+$/iu", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Is this the case for the other mb functions?

Comment: Not really as there are no appliance for most of them - there are functions in CI_Form_validation using strlen like above (max_length, min_length, exact_length) and some others that use preg_match function (alpha, alpha_numeric etc) - those don't work on unicode string, but you can easily forge them by using 'u' modifier - check my edited answer

Comment: @dezco To bad, is this an issue specifically with codeigniter or do all frameworks have this issue where it isnt built for utf8 by default for doing string functions?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't, but you can extend the form validation class to use your own validation functions.